# Browserify hides modules when names conflict with builtins

Tags: gulp, browserify

I have a module named `constants`. Browserify fails to bundle this module as its name conflicts with the builtin module defined in `lib/builtins`:

```
exports.constants = require.resolve('constants-browserify');
```

This effect can be observed in the generated code. For example, a module that depends upon `constants` shows:

```
{
  //...
  12:[
    function(require,module,exports){...},
    {"util":6,"constants":2}
  ]
```

We see that module 12 depends upon module 2 (the index of `constants`). The definition of the module with index 2 is:

```
2:[
  function(require,module,exports){
    module.exports={
      "O_RDONLY": 0,
      "O_WRONLY": 1,
      "O_RDWR": 2
      // ...
    }
  },
  {}
]
```

Those `O_*` constants are defined in `constants-browserify`, not in my `constants` module.

I'm using the NPM package from within Gulp and specify the following [options](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#var-b--browserifyfiles-or-opts):

```
return browserify('./main.js', {
        basedir: './scripts/app/',
        paths: ['./scripts/app/'],
        builtins: []
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

I'd hoped that specifying `builtins` as `[]` (I tried `{}` too) would override this behaviour, but it seems to only resolve the module as `undefined` in the generated code:

```
12:[
  function(require,module,exports){...},
  {"util":6,"constants":undefined}
 ]
```

Questions:

- Primary: Is there a way to tell browserify to not attempt to replace my module?
- Why does browserify want to specify these built ins? I don't see how they're needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only approach I've found that works is to manually exclude the builtins that you are having collisions with.

Assuming you're having collisions with `constants` and `null`, you would use:

```
browserify('./main.js', {
    builtins: {constants:null, util:null}
});
```

Comment: I created an [issue regarding this topic](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/925).